# Plot set of lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, lines

I have a matrix with a set points, divided in groups of 10 (example below). Each group of points corresponds to a line; how can I plot all lines?

Here is an example of how the matrix is organised:

```
y = [
109.41  110.55  111.69  112.83  113.96  115.10  116.24  117.37  118.51  119.65
56.87   56.21   55.55   54.89   54.23   53.57   52.91   52.25   51.5    50.92
-265.16 -263.07 -260.99 -258.90 -256.81 -254.73 -252.64 -250.55 -248.47 -246.38 ];
```

This is the code I am using to produce the matrix and try to plot all the lines:

```
for line = (1:n)
    for point = (1:10) 
        y(line,point) = [Y(line)-point*sin(Omega(line))];
    end
end

plot(0:1000,y,'linewidth',2)
```

Comment: I edited the question, adding the code I am using now.

Comment: Please, try not to [use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab), especially [`j*sin()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) can be very misleading...

Comment: What is `n`? what is `Y` and `Omega` how are they relate to the 10x3 numbers you posted at the beginning of your question? Please, take a minute and edit your question to make it sensible.

Comment: what is wrong with the plot you got from the `plot` command?

Comment: I get the error `Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.`

Comment: I suppose `n` is 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not surprised you got the error you have with the code you are using. `size(0:1000)` is `1x1001`. What size is your matrix `y`?

With the data you have provided, I would use the following:

```
y = [109.41  110.55  111.69  112.83  113.96  115.10  116.24  117.37  118.51  119.65; ...
56.87   56.21   55.55   54.89   54.23   53.57   52.91   52.25   51.5    50.92; ...
-265.16 -263.07 -260.99 -258.90 -256.81 -254.73 -252.64 -250.55 -248.47 -246.38];

plot(0:100:900,y,'linewidth',2) % size(0:100:900) is 1x10 and size(y) is 3x10 so we're good
```

This gives the following result (in Octave, should be exactly the same in MATLAB):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Y` is of size `1`-by-`n`, `Omega` is of size `1`-by-`n`, then you can avoid the nested loop:

```
 y = bsxfun( @minus, Y, bsxfun( @times, (1:10)', sin( Omega ) ) ); %'
 plot( 1:n, y, 'LineWidth', 2 );
```